# PHP Security JSON

Tags: php, android, json, security

I have this PHP Script that receives data from an android Application. What Security methods are used to ensure that this PHP script is secure?! like isset function?!

```
<?php 
require ('config.php');
$connection=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$movie_name=$obj['movie_name'];
mysqli_query($connection,"insert into  movie (movie_id, movie_name) VALUES (NULL,'$movie_name');");
echo "inserted";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection and has no validation at all.  You should also close your mysqli connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your example code to check for connection / json_decode failing, and to make use of prepared statements. You might consider doing some validation on the movie name e.g. is it shorter than the length of the database field for example. However, the prepared statements should stop any SQL injection:

```
<?php 
require ('config.php');

$connection=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
if (!$connection) {
  // mysql connection failed - error
  exit();
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

if( $obj == null ) {
  // json decode failed
  exit();
}

$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO movie (movie_id, movie_name) VALUES (NULL, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $obj['movie_name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

echo "inserted";
```